# How to make files in Linux folder with default group write permission

Tags: bash, shell

I have the folder called backups. The root is putting backups in that folder.
I want that all the files which are created in that folder should have group write permission.

I know i can use umask but i want to know that will umask work for all the files any where or it will work on particular folder.

e,g i want umask for only /backups folder not any where else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use [access control lists](http://acl.bestbits.at/man/man5/acl.txt). The filesystem containing `/backups` needs to be mounted with the `acl` option. Then give access to the group that should have it:

```
setfacl -d -Rm group:backup-group:rwx /backups
setfacl -Rm group:backup-group:rwx /backups
```

All subsequently created files and directories under `/backups` will be writable by `backup-group`, unless the backup program explicitly uses restrictive permissions (if it's storing archive files of some kind, you'll be ok, but if it's e.g. `rsync` preserving permissions, that won't do).

Another possibiliyt is to use [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) to provide a view of `/backups` (mounted at a different location) with different permissions.